# Unable To Update Email to phoneAutheticated Account in Flutter Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

My Flutter app has phoneAuthentication on success of authentication ,  user is directed to dashboard if email is added to account otherwise complete profile screen is shown , on entering email by user and on submit updateEmail(email) is called but , I am getting error at this poist with following lines of code .

```
external static Never _throw(Object error, StackTrace stackTrace);
```

Please help me to solve this error .

```
 final user =FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
     if (user != null) {
      try {
            user .updateEmail(emailController.text) .then((value) => print('Success'))
      .onError((error, stackTrace) => print(stackTrace));  } catch (error) {
                                      print(error);
                                    }
                                  } else {
                                    print('Found User Null');
                                  }
```

Comment: Please don't repost the same question multiple times on Stack Overflow. At best they will be closed, but it may get you banned from the site.

Comment: I have got any answer for my question i asked a day before so thats why i reposted .

Comment: That's not how Stack Overflow works though, and it may get you banned from the site. See [What do I do if my question has received no answers or comments?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261078/what-do-i-do-if-my-question-has-received-no-answers-or-comments) and [Should I repost a relevant, upvoted question without answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295092/should-i-repost-a-relevant-upvoted-question-without-answer)